# How can I erase every text on even line?

Tags: text, macros, editing

I have a text below

```
a
１つの
able
できる
about
およそ
above
上で
across
横切って
act
行動
afraid
恐れている
after
後に
afternoon
午後
again
再び
against
に対して
age
年齢
```

I just want to erase 2nd text likes `１つの`, `できる`, `およそ` .etc

I'd like them with Sublime text2 or something text editer.
Could you kindly tell me how to do it?

Kind Regards,
Kai00

Comment: I need to remain English words only in the text file.

Comment: So really you want to delete alternate lines?  Paste into a spreadsheet & sort

Comment: That is a great idea! I have done what I want to do. I appreciate you, Alex K.